# いくら＋pronoun＋でも usage/meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning

I am trying to translate this statement and understand the use of いくら:

> いくら俺でも鬼じゃあるまいしアルバムまで捨てたりは...

I think it means something like:

> I'm not an ogre so throwing away even an album...

if someone could correct my translation and explain the grammar behind the いくら俺でも part, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

> 「いくら + (Person) + でも + Negative expression」

is a common and important sentence pattern.  It being Japanese, however, ***the negative expression is often left unsaid***.  The non-sentence in question is a stereotypical example of this phenomenon.

> 「いくら俺{おれ}でも鬼{おに}じゃあるまいしアルバムまで捨{す}てたりは・・・」

What is left unsaid here (and instead "expressed" with 「・・・」) would surely be a negative phrase like 「しない」、「しないよ」、「しないさ」, etc.

> "However (adjective that fits the context) (the person) may be, he would not do ~~~."

is the meaning of this sentence pattern.  To apply this to your "non-sentence", one would come up with a translation like:

> "However ***evil*** I may be, I am no ogre and I ***would not go so far as to*** throw out an album."

I just selected the adjective "***evil***" and the phrase "***would not***" for the sake of translation.  Clearly, those are not found in the original.

The key is to know what is left unsaid; otherwise, you will not be able to translate something like this into English or other languages.

Answer (score 0):

"いくら俺でも" implicates "みんな良く知っているように、俺は善人ではない。多少は酷いことをした奴（人間）だ。しかし、さすがにそんな俺でも"

"いくら俺でも、鬼じゃあるまいし" => I admit that I'm not a good person. If I were a devil, I thrown away the album (that is something very special for you,) but I'm not as bad as devil. So I never do it.